# Convert multiple columns to a existing column

Tags: r, reshape2

My data looks like:

```
data.frame(name=c("city","village"),code=c(10322,10321),plz=c(7041,7043),plz1=c(7044,7044),plz2=c(7043,NA))
```

What's the smartest way to convert column **plz1** and column **plz2** to plz:

```
name  code   plz

city  10322  7041

city  10322  7044

city  10322  7043
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we `melt`, to get all the `plz` values into one column (moving from "wide" to "long" format). Then we just remove the "variable" column because we don't need to differentiate between `plz` and `plz1`, and we rename `value` to `plz`.

```
require(reshape2)

df1 <- data.frame(name=c("city","village"),code=c(10322,10321),plz=c(7041,7043),plz1=c(7044,7044),plz2=c(7043,NA))

df1 <- melt(df1, id.vars=c("name", "code"))

df1 <- df1[,-3]

names(df1) <- c("name", "code", "plz")

     name  code  plz
1    city 10322 7041
2 village 10321 7043
3    city 10322 7044
4 village 10321 7044
5    city 10322 7043
6 village 10321   NA
```

We can simplify a little further incorporating the `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)

df1 %>% melt(id.vars=c("name", "code")) %>% 
  select(-variable) %>% 
  rename(plz=value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tidyr and dplyr packages.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("city","village"),code=c(10322,10321), plz=c(7041,7043),plz1=c(7044,7044),plz2=c(7043,NA))
df %>% tidyr::gather(type, plz, plz:plz2) %>% dplyr::select(-type) %>% dplyr::filter(name == 'city')

#name   code    plz
#city   10322   7041
#city   10322   7044
#city   10322   7043
```